# Sencha Touch 2 PhoneGap missing js file

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have a plain vanilla Sencha Touch app running just fine on my Chrome browser.

Attempting to deploy it to an Android device I executed: `sencha app build native`.

The problem now is the app now generates the error below:

```
GET http://mysite/TestApp/phonegap.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The **app.json** file has the following code:

```
"js": [
    {
            "path": "phonegap.js",
            "remote": true
        },
.
.
.
```

Obviously, my problem is I can't locate the phonegap.js file.

Comment: Do you see a 'phonegap' folder under your project folder. TestApp/phonegap folder should exist.

Comment: @Kathir: Yes, the phonegap folder exists in the project base directory

Comment: When did you get this phonegap.js error, when you tried on the browser or device? It is expected to produce the phonegap.js not found error on the desktop browser.
Did you try running sencha app build -run native with an emulator running?

Comment: I am also Having the same problem using the cordova build.
After creating sencha app (i am using sencha cmd 5) i run `sencha cordova init com.xxxx.xxxx Xxxxx` to initialize cordova with sencha. after that i am geting `GET http://localhost/proximity/cordova.js 404 (Not Found) ` error... Please help to resolve this.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dFx6J.png Please find the print screen regarding the same